# Eclipse internal error cannot load java tooling after svn conflict on EJB project

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ejb

I use eclipse kepler, I've downloaded svn from eclipse marketplace with all proper connectors.

I'm developing a very simple java enterprise application.

I have a Ear project, EJB client project, EJB project, Web project, all correctly bound.

My code is here:

```
https://code.google.com/p/tralve-dreams-group-handic-app/source/browse/
```

The problem is the following:

I have commited all 4 project and I got a conflict on some config document of EJB. Being that I didnt modified at all that project I just commited the other 3 projects and deleted them 4 from my laptop for a brand new checkout.

Now what happens is that when I download the project all the annotations of the beans cannot be resolved as well as their imports (e.g. @Stateless cannot be resolved) and if I restart Eclipse with these projects opened the IDE just falls into several internal errors like "cannot download java tooling" or build error.

Of course I can't deploy on my glassfish 4.0 server because it can't find any ejb.

If someone know something I beg him to asnwer this as soon as possible, the IDE is now useless I have an important deadline in few days.

I have already tried to delete workspace .metadata. 
This is what i get from the .log:

```
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core 4 -1 2014-01-26 23:33:44.910
!MESSAGE No property tester contributes a property oracle.eclipse.tools.common.wtp.core.fproj.containsRuntimeComponentType to type class org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.runtime.internal.BridgedRuntime
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: No property tester contributes a property oracle.eclipse.tools.common.wtp.core.fproj.containsRuntimeComponentType to type class org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.runtime.internal.BridgedRuntime
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtensionManager.getProperty(TypeExtensionManager.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TestExpression.evaluate(TestExpression.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.IterateExpression.evaluate(IterateExpression.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.WithExpression.evaluate(WithExpression.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.EnablementExpression.evaluate(EnablementExpression.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core.libprov.internal.LibraryProvider.isEnabledFor(LibraryProvider.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.AbstractJpaProject.validateLibraryProvider_(AbstractJpaProject.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.AbstractJpaProject.validateLibraryProvider(AbstractJpaProject.java:1462)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.AbstractJpaProject.validate(AbstractJpaProject.java:1455)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.AbstractJpaProject.getValidationMessages(AbstractJpaProject.java:1445)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.buildValidationMessages_(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager$BuildValidationMessagesCommand.execute(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.common.core.internal.utility.command.CommandJobCommandAdapter.execute(CommandJobCommandAdapter.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.common.core.internal.utility.command.JobCommandJob.run(JobCommandJob.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.expressions 4 201 2014-01-26 23:33:44.911
!MESSAGE No property tester contributes a property oracle.eclipse.tools.common.wtp.core.fproj.containsRuntimeComponentType to type class org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.runtime.internal.BridgedRuntime
```

Comment: These kind of errors are hard to debug and resolve. Try unzip the new eclipse.

Comment: sadly i have already changed eclipse, it seems like the problem comes with the project

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the internet doesn't know about this error. 
Unzip another eclipse, uninstall glassfish and reinstall.